# C++ only last call of SetConsoleCursorPosition() is working

Tags: c++, windows

Code below outputs text in last gotoxy() cordinates, if I put cin  in the middle, then it works, cursor is at different positions. How could I change cursor position for every word?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

void gotoxy( short x, short y ) 
{ 
    HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE) ; 
    COORD position = { x, y } ; 

    SetConsoleCursorPosition( hStdout, position ) ; 
} 
int main() {
    gotoxy(5,5);
    cout << "Test";
    gotoxy(10,10);
    cout << "Test";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't need input, I need only to output text and change cursors position

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is (probably) buffered IO. The output streams do not write to the output until they see a newline `'\n'`, input is done (this is called tied streams in C++) or `std::flush` or `std::endl` is sent to the output stream.

Flush can also be done by calling `std::cout.flush()`.

Comment: You are a life saver ! Thanks mate